# how to include one html file to another html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 HTML files, suppose a.html and b.html. In a.html I want to include b.html. using javascript.

Comment: is the above code doesn't work?

Comment: It's working. It shows the new window.  But how to show my parent class in the popup page?

Answer (score 0):

You could just

```
<button id="btn">Click Here</button>
```

then you have your script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn').on("click",function() {
           window.open ("","MsgWindow", "width = 700, height = 500");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here you have the fiddle with jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/0znn4trr/1/

Here is the fiddle in pure javascript.

https://jsfiddle.net/za8e2rg6/

Comment: Because for this user need to use jquery. That you not mentioned

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja - I also made a fiddle for pure javascript.

Answer (score -1):

refer the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWindow(){
    var mywindow = window.open ("","MsgWindow", "width = 700, height = 500");
}

</script>

<html>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="openWindow()"> Click Me !! </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can anyone say why -1 is given ?